# How to disable AmbientTransaction when calling Stored Proc from a Helper Class?

Tags: sql, biztalk, biztalk-2013, msdtc

I am trying to call a Stored Proc using a C# helper class in my BizTalk solution. I am able to call the stored proc when I use a Send port with WCF-Custom adapter and set AmbientTrancsaction to "false". However I get a DTC error when trying to call the stored proc using the Helper class.

Is there a way to disable the transactions from the helper method itself.

Comment: If you aren't using `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction` or `SqlTransaction` in your C# helper, then there is no reason for it to require transactions. Use a regular `SqlCommand` call with `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. Maybe the stored procedure is built to require transactions from the client side? Also i suggest you don't include BizTalk in your tags, as your actual question is not related to BizTalk at all, you only performed some trail-and-error testing with it... @AasthaK

Comment: So why are you using a helper class rather than using the Adapter?